# How do I control the title of instances of a class in Python?

Tags: python, class

Purely a cosmetic thing, but when I create a class in python, how do I control its instances' titles? e.g. for

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
```

I can then create an instance:

```
>> f = Foo('bar')
>> f
<Foo instance at 0x10ab41a28>
```

If I wanted that to return `bar`, what would I do? (In Django, you use the `__unicode__` method of the class, but I've tried setting both `__unicode__` and `__str__` functions to return `self.name`, and while these work on their own, they don't affect the value of the class.)

Comment: You know you're creating an instance there not a class?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean to control the title for instances of the class.

Comment: Do you just want to control the instance's string representation?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually define `__str__` to return a string representation, and then return the string in the `__repr__` method, like this:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     def __init__(self, name):
...          self.name = name
...     def __str__(self):
...          return '<Foo name=%s>' % self.name
...     def __repr__(self):
...          return str(self)
... 
>>> f = Foo('bar')
>>> f
<Foo name=bar>
```

For more info, see [Difference between **str** and **repr** in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Define `__repr__` instead - that will sort you out.

Comment: Thanks @kl-7 Using a touch device and it doesn't have the code escape symbol!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's not the problem with your class.

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

>>> f = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> f = Foo("bar")
>>> f
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f2a9b9b7590>
>>> print(f)
bar
```

The problem is that by just typing `f`, you'll get the output of `repr()` instead of `str()`. If you want to change that, you'll need to define `__repr__` instead of `__str__` or `__unicode__`.

Usually, you'll be using the `str()` output anyways (print uses it, when coercing to string it gets used). `repr()` is really only used if you ask for it, like with:

```
>>> print("{0!r}".format(f))
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f2a9b9b7590>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up a few things,

You set the name of the class when you used `Class Foo:`. This created a `class` whose name was `Foo`.

Now, when you do `f = Foo('bar')` and then `f`, the interpreter handily calls your instance's `__repr__` method:

```
>>> class Foo():
...  def __repr__(self):
...   return 'REPR'
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> 
>>> f
REPR
>>>
```

Long story short, use the `__repr__` method if you want to control what the interpreter returns when you write `f`.

If you don't, the interpreter will more-or-less do it for you:

```
>>> class F():
...  pass
... 
>>> f = F()
>>> f.__repr__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: F instance has no attribute '__repr__'
>>> repr(f)
'<__main__.F instance at 0x7f00381e2368>'
```